# HTTPS Status: 404 Not Found in rails REST api for all routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise

I am currently developing REST API using rails by following this tutorial http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_two. I am using postman to test the routes but i am getting 404 response code for all actions.

[This is my available routes in screentshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLk40.png)

This is the content of my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
     devise_for :users
     namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json },
            constraints: { subdomain: 'api'}, path: '/' do

        resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
        resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
   end
end
```

I am using devise for authenticating the user.

Comment: does your postman makes request with subdomain included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had been going through this tutorial too. Had the same issue - all of my routes didn't work so I couldn't perform any request with Postman.

What I did was removing that from `routes.rb`

```
, constraints: { subdomain: 'api'}, path: '/'
```

And according to the tutorial you may want to add the scope and versioning to your routes:

```
scope module: :v1, 
  constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
```

But it's up to you (don't know how close you follow the tutorial)

So your code will look like that:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
     devise_for :users
     namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
       #optional
       scope module: :v1, 
         constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
         resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
         resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
       end
   end
end
```

After that my requests started to work the following way:

```
localhost:3000/api/users/1
```